# The "This is a favorite question" Button

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design

Is there a way we can change the "favorite" button across the entire site (there should be one directly to the left of this question)? I find it somewhat ironic to have a pentagram incorporated into a site about Judaism, given its symbolisms http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram.

Comment: I think all the beta sites have that picture. (But that doesn't answer your question.)

Comment: Perhaps we should just think of it as a star (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_polygon) instead (which I assume it is in this case). At least for me the shape doesn't conjure (no pun) any religious ideas.

Comment: As a doodler who spent some part of high school drawing stars with as many different numbers of points as possible, I agree with WAF. It's just a doodle.

Comment: @Isaac, I agree - but this is something to keep in mind, for when the site goes live and we can get a specific design. A *magen david* would be great to replace it with...

Comment: @AviD By all means. I hope there's a great deal of discussion of all the design elements, leading eventually to an awesome, distinctly Jewish, site design.

Comment: @AviD - While we're at it, how about a little pointing hand? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/261b/index.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems in the [new beta design](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/862/759), this issue is solved as the star doesn't have the inside lines.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth discussing alternatives for this glyph that could be part of the [site design](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384/design-for-judaism-se) when we launch, eventually. However, I think the consensus is generally that the sketchy five-pointed start we have now is just an inoffensive doodle and not worth trying to change ahead of time.