# Scholar badge fit with this site?

Tags: discussion, badges

I just happened upon the [scholar badge](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/10/scholar), which seems to be [an inherited badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/10/scholar). To get it, one must ask and answer a question. With our rich tradition of venerating our scholars, who are our elite, our tzaddikim, our leaders and most honoured, doesn't it seem a tad *too* silly for this site? (I get that it's deliberately silly, because it is light hearted, and in any other context I wouldn't even notice). If so, is it possible to change the wording for Mi Yodeya?

Or am *I* the one being too silly?

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3867/759

Answer (score 2):

To be a "Scholar," you must "Ask a question and accept an answer." In other words:

- Ask a question.
- Read the answers you receive.
- Grant recognition to the one you find most helpful, showing gratitude to its author and helping direct others' attention to it.

These actions are reminiscent of some of the 48 Habits of Highly Torah-Acquisitive People found in [Perek Kinyan Torah](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.6.6?lang=bi&with=all), such as:

- בִּשְׁמִיעַת הָאֹזֶן - Attentive listening
- בְּדִקְדּוּק חֲבֵרִים - By critical give and take with friends
- מַעֲמִידוֹ עַל הָאֱמֶת - Who leads [his colleague] on to truth
- שׁוֹאֵל וּמֵשִׁיב - Who asks and answers
- שׁוֹמֵעַ וּמוֹסִיף - Who listens [to others], and [himself] adds [to his knowledge]
- וְהַמְכַוֵּן אֶת שְׁמוּעָתוֹ - Who is exact in what he has learned,
- וְהָאוֹמֵר דָּבָר בְּשֵׁם אוֹמְרוֹ - And who says a thing in the name of him who said it

Far from silliness, it seems to me that the Scholar badge reinforces behaviors that are consistent with habits that our tradition recommends for those who aspire to scholarship.

Comment: A worthy defense. Although, it seems to be mainly a defense for changing the badge to "Aspiring Scholar"?

Comment: @RabbiKaii as they say in the finest halls of Torah scholarship, "Nu, nu."