# Can we have a nice 404 image for mi.yodeya?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Design Ideas for 404, Captcha, and Error pages](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/design-ideas-for-404-captcha-and-error-pages)

Can we have a nice 404 image for mi.yodeya?

Right now it is kind of boring....

[image]