# Contest proposal - 404 error

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Design Ideas for 404, Captcha, and Error pages](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/design-ideas-for-404-captcha-and-error-pages)

I propose we have a contest to come up with a [site-specific 404 Error page](http://www.rollingstones.com/404) (3 Weeks Warning: Turn speakers off before clicking the link, as it will immediately play music) to replace [the current one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/404).

We could even have a separate contest for meta!

Comment: Are there prizes involved?

Comment: We should check with [Jin](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/users/417/jin) before having a separate 404 page for Meta, as he may not be available to design two pages. Moreover, even if we choose one, it's up to him/SE to implement it. That said, how about this post *be* the contest? People can propose 404 pages as answers, whihc can get up-/downvoted. (If so, I think update the question to clarify that this is the contest.)

Comment: @DoubleAA, you mean besides having your design on the 404 page? `:-)`

Comment: Hm, actually, [we already have a whole list of suggestions](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1018), my comment above that this be a call for more such may not be the wisest. In fact, SethJ, what are you proposing that's not covered there already?

Comment: Double aa, and @msh210 I didn't see that one. Whoops! Well, in any case, how about formalizing it (over there) into a contest with rep points as the prize?

Comment: @SethJ Whose rep points?

Comment: @doubleaa Community's?

Comment: @SethJ It doesn't seem like [w/s/he has much to give](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

Comment: @doubleaa, true...

Comment: The only way to award rep is with a bounty. Anyone volunteering to offer it?

Comment: @msh210 Only if I can set the terms.

Comment: @SethJ, you can offer bounty to whomever you want: of course you set the terms. While official word from SE is that setting bounty for any reason other than for a good answer (the one being award the bounty) is frowned upon, they acknowledge that there's really nothing they can do to stop it and they don't forbid it.