# Why were we left with boring 404 and error pages?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design

There were so many great ideas proposed [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1018/5151). How come none got implemented?

My personal favorites are these for [error](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1026/5151) and [404](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1020/5151).

Comment: Odd. The CAPTCHA was implemented, but not the others.

Comment: @TRiG http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17441559#17441559 || http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17452471#17452471

Comment: Somewhat relevant, though not particularly helpful: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=12916283#12916283

Comment: Per current votes (and based on those answers and comments thereon), the 404 page would have "Would you believe that I toiled, trying to find the URL you asked for, but did not succeed? Wait; don't answer that." or similar, & the error page would have "We have erred." and a photo/GIF of someone's hand tapping his chest as in http://lambdapublishers.com/year/images_english/tishrei/vidul.jpg http://www.frumsatire.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/vidui-150x150.jpg http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-EdjbuGhQJG8/UFMqmIYhIBI/AAAAAAAAArk/KfVtCRlik_g/s1600/vidui.jpg .