# Change or choose Hebrew font?

Tags: feature-request, support, design, hebrew, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there anything we can do about the Hebrew font used on the main site?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/is-there-anything-we-can-do-about-the-hebrew-font-used-on-the-main-site)

I don't really like the font in which Hebrew is displayed on our site. Can I petition for it to be changed? Or is there some way to change it for me only on my browser? Also, vowel points tend to be mispositioned. Is there some way of correcting that?

Comment: I really like the font "Narkisim" for Hebrew.

Comment: @DoubleAA I love it too! But how to change the current one?...

Comment: Now that we have a new, permanent site theme, this question, about the old one, is irrelevant. And someone's asked [the same question about the new theme](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1182). I think the best thing to do now would be to close this one as too localized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to view the site in a font you have installed on your machine, you can set a user stylesheet (if your browser allows you to) that includes `body,*{font-family:'Name-of-font' !important}`. Note that that will apply to English as well as Hebrew words on the site. To use it only for titles, posts, and comments, use `.post-text,.post-text *,.comment-copy,h1{font-family:'Name-of-font' !important}`. As far as changing it for everyone, well, for the current (beta) theme, that request should go in [the question about the new theme](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/862); for the theme we get when we graduate out of beta, I suppose this question can serve as a feature request.