# Is there anything we can do about the Hebrew font used on the main site?

Tags: feature-request, design, hebrew, font

Is there anything we can do about the Hebrew font used on the main site?

See my question [Does anyone have a proof text that animals *don't* have spirits?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/does-anyone-have-a-proof-text-that-animals-dont-have-spirits).

I quoted הירדת היא למטה לארץ and the daleth of hayoredes looks very like a zayin when the site is viewed so the whole page fits the scereen. It gets better as it is magnified. .

See related question [Change or choose Hebrew font?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/900/change-or-choose-hebrew-font). This now a feature request.

Comment: It looks good to me. Can you recommend a specific font as better?

Comment: If you write 'daleth' why not 'hayoredeth'?

Comment: @DoubleAA We did. http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/hebrew-in-comments-and-sidebars-is-too-small-to-read

Comment: @HodofHod Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the Georgia font, which is used for this site, doesn't have a Hebrew implementation, and therefore the font that is used is the next in line of declaration -  Times New Roman - which doesn't look good in Hebrew.

As far as I know, Arial font is the recommendation for Hebrew on the web. While I haven't tried this method, there is a way to define a font family for a set of character, using the font-range property [that is described here](http://24ways.org/2011/creating-custom-font-stacks-with-unicode-range/).

Could something like that be done here?

Comment: That method (per the blog post) isn't supported in Firefox.  Maybe it makes more sense to use a font that *just* defines Hebrew characters?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman - the post does have a solution for FF too. And could you please explain how a font that just defines Hebrew characters would help? What would happen to the English characters?

Comment: Basically, the solution it suggests would not change anything for FF users, but only WebKit and IE users.  I assume, maybe wrongly, that if Georgia doesn't define Hebrew chars, then it falls through to Times, then we can instead use a font that defines only Hebrew chars which will fall through to Georgia for English (and Arabic, Sumerian, etc.)

Comment: Yes, @CharlesKoppelman, you're right about FF. And I like your idea of fall-through from Hebrew fonts. I've never used fonts that defined only Hebrew chars, but I've run into [this post](http://tomercohen.com/2012/04/12/גופנים-חופשיים-חינמיים-בעברית) before, and now I tried to pick out from there [links](http://www.oketz.com/fonts/all.html) to [fonts](http://gofania.blogspot.co.il/) that seem to define only [Hebrew](http://fonti.come2us.co.il/fonts.htm) [chars](http://www.mendelsson.co.il/yakov/myfonts.htm)

Comment: On second thought, @CharlesKoppelman, I think the Hebrew font *can* define Latin fonts too, the same way Times New Roman does. Georgia will be the first on the list, and that will take care of the Latin fonts, but the next font could be something else - It could be Arial (which all OS's have), or any other Hebrew font that goes well with Georgia. There is a new font named [Aleph](http://alef.hagilda.com/) that seems to be "in style" lately, but I'm no designer, so I don't know if it fits in with the Georgia font (which I like)